# Generic PHP form processor

Tags: php, forms, post, get, request

I'm trying to create an elegant form processor that can receive POST OR GET and cycle thru the values and display them. I'd like to make it as simple/elegant as possible, and can't seem to eliminate GET/POST in favor of REQUEST. This code outputs an extra value pair, and I clearly don't understand the relationship of GET/POST to REQUEST. The form includes previous GET information when POST is used (so they seem to overlap) and I'm not sure how to easily NOT include the cookie (I think that's what it is) value. I understand REQUEST is not the best way to do this, but wondering still if there's not a cool way to use it in this fashion. Open to other suggestions.

```
<h1>
    Welcome to the Flexiform! AKA "The Formerator"
</h1>
<p>
This form should process any combination of inputs... this iteration doesn't handle identically-named inputs other than checkboxes. Would like to figure that out.
</p>

<?php

if ($_GET || $_POST) 
//if ($_REQUEST)   // why can't I use this?... it seems to process the incoming page as GET on firstload... 
{
    echo ("<h2>Way to '" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] . "' some! </h2>");

    foreach($_REQUEST as $submittedName => $submittedValue)     
    {   
        if (is_array($submittedValue)) // for checkboxes with more than one selected value
        {         
            $submittedValue = implode(', ', $submittedValue); 
        }                

        echo "For the <b>" . $submittedName . " input, you submitted: :</b> " . $submittedValue."</br>";
    }
}
else 
{
    echo ("<h2>Please submit one of the two forms to see some results.</h2>");
}

?>

<hr><hr>
<br>
GET SOME!
<form action= "" method = "get" >
    <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "GIcabad" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name2" value = "GIcabad2" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name3" value = "GIcabad3" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "GIcabadbb" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name2" value = "GIcabad2bb" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name3" value = "GIcabad3bb" />
    orange:<input type = "checkbox" name = "colors[]" value = "orange" checked />
    red:<input type = "checkbox" name = "colors[]" value = "red" />
    pink:<input type = "checkbox" name = "colors[]" value = "pink" checked />
    <input type = "submit" />       
</form>
<br>
POST SOME!
<form action = "" method= "post" >
    <input type = "text" name = "name" value = "PIcabad" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name2" value = "PIcabad2" />
    <input type = "text" name = "name3" value = "PIcabad3" />
    <input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: is there a question in here?

Comment: `$_REQUEST` is `$_POST` + `$_GET` So if you got to this page using a GET and querystring, that will also appear in your `$_REQUEST`

Comment: You can try `foreach(array($_GET, $_POST) as $submittedName => $submittedValue)`

Comment: @RiggsFolly `$_REQUEST` includes `$_COOKIE` too

Comment: @Mike Not on my PHP `request_order = "GP"` But you are right it could be, I forgot about that

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hmm.. looks like conflicting information in the php.net website. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php says it includes all 3 by default and http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order says "the default distribution php.ini files does not contain the 'C' for cookies, due to security concerns."

Comment: Just note that that order is variable.  Which puts me off $_REQUEST

Comment: @RahulDev that's interesting, and i'm playing with it - but it complicates the output.. .since i'm trying to say, "For item firstname, you entered David". So i have to do more nested looping/checking.

Comment: I've modified this- so now the results seem predictable... but i still feel like the code is not as elegant as it needs to be- is there no way to avoid the if/else? http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gkis-nu9z

Answer (score 0):

You can loop it once on the main file of your application and store the `$_GET` and `$_POST` inside a single variable ( It will act like `$_REQUEST` but w/o `$_COOKIES` ). Then you can use it like this

```
<?php 

$input_values = array();
$gpcs = array_merge($_POST, $_GET);
foreach ($gpcs as $key => $value) {
    $input_values[$key] = $value;
}


// Then you can use anywhere in your application like this
echo isset($input_values['username'])? $input_values['username']:'';
echo isset($input_values['password'])? $input_values['password']:'';
echo isset($input_values['user_type'])? $input_values['user_type']:'';

?>
```

Edit: **Form and Result**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="demo" value="Demo"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="demo2" value="Demo 2"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="array[]" value="Array 1"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="array[]" value="Array 2"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="array[]" value="Array 3"><br/>
    <input type="text" name="array[]" value="Array 4"><br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

Array
(
    [demo] => Demo
    [demo2] => Demo 2
    [array] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array 1
            [1] => Array 2
            [2] => Array 3
            [3] => Array 4
        )

)
```

Comment: what if the user posts an array input?

Comment: @Cemal Yes, it does handle arrays. I updated the answer with output of `$input_values`

Comment: I think you'll get a `Notice: Array to string conversion in...` if you echo instead of print_r

Comment: Naturally, Developer should know the type of result he is expecting. Same error will occur when `echo $_GET/POST['array']`.

Comment: Well he mentioned that it can be of any type regardles for any therefore your code will not be able to handle it.

Comment: I cannot find anything related to "any type" in his post. He wanted to eliminate cookies from `$_REQUEST`, so the above code does and stores every value in a single variable. Lastly, he is imploding the arrays in his codes which can also be done on above code as well but that doesn't make sense to me. It can be imploded later on when required.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong. The html part in the code was telling that it wouldn't handle arrays. So yours is right. I think the OP is expecting your answer to be in his code though. (seeing he has not accepted it yet)

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess i'm just not being clear in my question. Let me try again. What is the best way to code a form handler that DOES NOT KNOW the METHOD or the NUMBER or the NAMES or the TYPES of any of the fields being sent to it. It should output user-friendly results MORE OR LESS in the form of: You submitted name-value for value-value. It should handle checkboxes, but doesn't need to handle files.